# Why is a Cell used to create unmovable objects?

Tags: rust

So I ran into [this code snippet](https://gist.github.com/Kimundi/d846f1da490ef4e9b0d9) showing how to create "unmoveable" types in Rust - moves are prevented because the compiler treats the object as borrowed for its whole lifetime.

```
use std::cell::Cell;
use std::marker;

struct Unmovable<'a> {
    lock: Cell<marker::ContravariantLifetime<'a>>,
    marker: marker::NoCopy
}

impl<'a> Unmovable<'a> {
    fn new() -> Unmovable<'a> {
        Unmovable { 
            lock: Cell::new(marker::ContravariantLifetime),
            marker: marker::NoCopy
        }
    }
    fn lock(&'a self) {
        self.lock.set(marker::ContravariantLifetime);
    }
    fn new_in(self_: &'a mut Option<Unmovable<'a>>) {
        *self_ = Some(Unmovable::new());
        self_.as_ref().unwrap().lock();
    }
}

fn main(){
    let x = Unmovable::new();
    x.lock();

    // error: cannot move out of `x` because it is borrowed
    // let z = x; 

    let mut y = None;
    Unmovable::new_in(&mut y);

    // error: cannot move out of `y` because it is borrowed
    // let z = y; 

    assert_eq!(std::mem::size_of::<Unmovable>(), 0)
}
```

I don't yet understand how this works. My guess is that the lifetime of the borrow-pointer argument is forced to match the lifetime of the lock field. The weird thing is, this code continues working in the same way if:

- I change `ContravariantLifetime<'a>` to `CovariantLifetime<'a>`, or to `InvariantLifetime<'a>`.
- I remove the body of the `lock` method.

But, if I remove the `Cell`, and just use `lock: marker::ContravariantLifetime<'a>` directly, as so:

```
use std::marker;

struct Unmovable<'a> {
    lock: marker::ContravariantLifetime<'a>,
    marker: marker::NoCopy
}

impl<'a> Unmovable<'a> {
    fn new() -> Unmovable<'a> {
        Unmovable { 
            lock: marker::ContravariantLifetime,
            marker: marker::NoCopy
        }
    }
    fn lock(&'a self) {
    }
    fn new_in(self_: &'a mut Option<Unmovable<'a>>) {
        *self_ = Some(Unmovable::new());
        self_.as_ref().unwrap().lock();
    }
}

fn main(){
    let x = Unmovable::new();
    x.lock();

    // does not error?
    let z = x;

    let mut y = None;
    Unmovable::new_in(&mut y);

    // does not error?
    let z = y;

    assert_eq!(std::mem::size_of::<Unmovable>(), 0)
}
```

Then the "Unmoveable" object is allowed to move. Why would that be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The true answer is comprised of a moderately complex consideration of lifetime [variancy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance_%28computer_science%29), with a couple of misleading aspects of the code that need to be sorted out.

For the code below, `'a` is an arbitrary lifetime, `'small` is an arbitrary lifetime that is smaller than `'a` (this can be expressed by the constraint `'a: 'small`), and `'static` is used as the most common example of a lifetime that is larger than `'a`.

Here are the facts and steps to follow in the consideration:

- Normally, lifetimes are *contravariant*; `&'a T` is contravariant with regards to `'a` (as is `T<'a>` in the absence of any variancy markers), meaning that if you have a `&'a T`, it’s OK to substitute a longer lifetime than `'a`, e.g. you can store in such a place a `&'static T` and treat it as though it were a `&'a T` (you’re allowed to shorten the lifetime).
- In a few places, lifetimes can be *invariant*; the most common example is `&'a mut T` which is invariant with regards to `'a`, meaning that if you have a `&'a mut T`, you cannot store a `&'small mut T` in it (the borrow doesn’t live long enough), but you also cannot store a `&'static mut T` in it, because that would cause trouble for the reference being stored as it would be forgotten that it *actually* lived for longer, and so you could end up with multiple simultaneous mutable references being created.
- A [`Cell`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.Cell.html) contains an [`UnsafeCell`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.UnsafeCell.html); what isn’t so obvious is that `UnsafeCell` is magic, being wired to the compiler for special treatment as the language item named “unsafe”. Importantly, `UnsafeCell<T>` is *invariant* with regards to `T`, for similar sorts of reasons to the invariance of `&'a mut T` with regards to `'a`.
- Thus, `Cell<any lifetime variancy marker>` will actually behave the same as `Cell<InvariantLifetime<'a>>`.
- Furthermore, you don’t actually need to use `Cell` any more; you can just use `InvariantLifetime<'a>`.
- Returning to the example with the `Cell` wrapping removed and a `ContravariantLifetime` (actually equivalent to just defining `struct Unmovable<'a>;`, for contravariance is the default as is no `Copy` implementation): why does it allow moving the value? … I must confess, I don’t grok this particular case yet and would appreciate some help myself in understanding why it’s allowed. It seems back to front, that covariance would allow the lock to be shortlived but that contravariance and invariance wouldn’t, but in practice it seems that only invariance is performing the desired function.

Anyway, here’s the final result. `Cell<ContravariantLifetime<'a>>` is changed to `InvariantLifetime<'a>` and that’s the only functional change, making the `lock` method function as desired, taking a borrow with an invariant lifetime. (Another solution would be to have `lock` take `&'a mut self`, for a mutable reference is, as already discussed, invariant; this is inferior, however, as it requires needless mutability.)

One other thing that needs mentioning: the contents of the `lock` and `new_in` methods are completely superfluous. The body of a function will never change the static behaviour of the compiler; only the signature matters. The fact that the lifetime parameter `'a` is marked invariant is the key point. So the whole “construct an `Unmovable` object and call `lock` on it”  part of `new_in` is completely superfluous. Similarly setting the contents of the cell in `lock` was a waste of time. (Note that it is again the invariance of `'a` in `Unmovable<'a>` that makes `new_in` work, not the fact that it is a mutable reference.)

```
use std::marker;

struct Unmovable<'a> {
    lock: marker::InvariantLifetime<'a>,
}

impl<'a> Unmovable<'a> {
    fn new() -> Unmovable<'a> {
        Unmovable { 
            lock: marker::InvariantLifetime,
        }
    }

    fn lock(&'a self) { }

    fn new_in(_: &'a mut Option<Unmovable<'a>>) { }
}

fn main() {
    let x = Unmovable::new();
    x.lock();

    // This is an error, as desired:
    let z = x;

    let mut y = None;
    Unmovable::new_in(&mut y);

    // Yay, this is an error too!
    let z = y;
}
```

Comment: Answered all my questions! Except for the one that doesn't seem answerable (why can you move with *either* `CovariantLifetime` *or* `ContravariantLifetime`?), which seems like another possible compiler bug. Thank you!

Comment: The stated invariance of `&'a mut T` is incorrect: it is invariant with respect to `T`, and contravariant with respect to `'a`. It is valid to coerce a `&'a mut T` to a `&'small mut T`.

Comment: Also, `InvarianceLifetime` is the intersection of `ContravarianceLifetime` and `CovarianceLifetime`, so it behaves like both in terms of restrictions. Each of the mark types actually represents removing funtionality, rather than adding it: `Contra...` is just *not* covariant, `Co...` is just not contravariant, and `In...` is neither covariant nor contravariant.

Answer (score 2):

An interesting problem! Here's my understanding of it...

Here's another example that doesn't use `Cell`:

```
#![feature(core)]

use std::marker::InvariantLifetime;

struct Unmovable<'a> { //'
    lock: Option<InvariantLifetime<'a>>, //'
}

impl<'a> Unmovable<'a> {
    fn lock_it(&'a mut self) { //'
        self.lock = Some(InvariantLifetime)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut u = Unmovable { lock: None };
    u.lock_it();
    let v = u;
}
```

([Playpen](http://is.gd/4uktlW))

The important trick here is that the structure needs to borrow *itself*. Once we have done that, it can no longer be moved because any move would invalidate the borrow. This isn't conceptually different from any other kind of borrow:

```
struct A(u32);

fn main() {
    let a = A(42);
    let b = &a;
    let c = a;
}
```

The only thing is that you need some way of letting the struct contain its own reference, which isn't possible to do at construction time. My example uses `Option`, which requires `&mut self` and the linked example uses `Cell`, which allows for interior mutability and just `&self`.

Both examples use a lifetime marker because it allows the typesystem to track the lifetime without needing to worry about a particular instance.

Let's look at your constructor:

```
fn new() -> Unmovable<'a> { //'
    Unmovable { 
        lock: marker::ContravariantLifetime,
        marker: marker::NoCopy
    }
}
```

Here, the lifetime put into `lock` is chosen *by the caller*, and it ends up being the normal lifetime of the `Unmovable` struct. There's no borrow of self.

Let's next look at your lock method:

```
fn lock(&'a self) {
}
```

Here, the compiler knows that the lifetime won't change. However, if we make it mutable:

```
fn lock(&'a mut self) {
}
```

Bam! It's locked again. This is because the compiler knows that the internal fields *could* change. We can actually apply this to our `Option` variant and remove the body of `lock_it`!

Comment: I'm under the impression that Rust should be able to track lifetimes and borrows across calls based strictly on function signatures, right? So if we kept the `Cell` around the `lock` field, the lifetime of that field is *still* determined by the caller... `Cell` grants interior mutability, but that isn't visible in the function prototype of `lock` in either case, so that shouldn't change outcomes from the borrow-checker, should it? Does the borrow-checker somehow understand that there's a possibility of mutation if the struct contains a `Cell`?

Comment: An excellent question. If no one more knowledgable comments here, I'd encourage submitting it as another top-level question.

Comment: This is kind of looking like a bug to me, at this point. I can't say clearly enough yet about what's going on, but changing the *type* of borrow should not change the *fact* of whether the variable is borrowed at the point that the move is attempted. Making the borrow `mut` really shouldn't have changed the lifetime of the borrow. And the move should be impossible even if the value is only borrowed immutably. Seems a little fishy... Either way, thanks for your help!

Comment: @AidanCully **even if the value is only borrowed immutably** - but note that if we were calling a `&self` method, then we know that the borrow cannot possibly live beyond the function call - there'd be no way to hold on to it! However, when using `&'a mut self`, with a corresponding field with `'a`, it's possible that the method modifies the struct to hold on to the lifetime. This still doesn't clear up the details about `Cell` though.

Comment: @Shepmaster: pay attention to the `&'a self`; that means that the method is only callable *if it can actually take that borrow*. If you have a function taking a `&Unmovable`, you will not be able to call `lock()` on it. (Incidentally, I do not agree with your analysis of the problem and agree with @Aidan that it looks like a bug.)

Comment: @ChrisMorgan noted! Do you disagree with all of my answer, or just a specific part? I look forward to learning more from your answer! ^_^

Comment: I tried running the above-linked playpen, and I’m getting errors that InvariantLifetime doesn’t exist in marker. Has this been removed from Rust since 2015?